# Angular 2 Http client not doing anything when called

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

TL;DR: Nothing happens when it hits `this.http.get()`

I've been following this tutorial here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html and tried making a few of the methods myself, but I am unable to make any requests to my server, being ASP.NET Core RC2.

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { RegistrationViewModel } from '../../account/registration';

@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getItems(): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:56340/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
                   .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

The code I am calling this method from calls it fine, I've walked through this with debugger, but nothing appears to happen when it hits the `http.get` line, I don't see anything in the network tab of Chrome or any sort of response.

The URL `http://localhost:56340/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts` works fine since I've put that into the browser by itself and it returns the sample data.
I've  also tried with just `'/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts'` with no results aswell

I am getting one TS error from Visual Studio:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type Observable

But I don't get any errors from angular in the console from it, so I think it might just be a typings issue since it is imported in my `main.ts` by importing `rxjs-operators` which contains `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

rxjs-operators.ts

```
// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Comment: Check the tutorial, you need to subscribe to get the data, or use an async pipe, create mydata var on class, in ngOnInit do this.mydata=this.getItems().  Then display in html `(mydata | async)  | json`

Comment: Ah ok yeah, it was due to the fact that I wasn't subscribing the service call from my Component, must have overlooked that part

Answer (score 3):

Add a `catch` to see any other errors you might have

```
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
      }
      private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
      }
```

Also try to import only the required modules:

```
// import 'rxjs/Rx'; // adds ALL RxJS statics & operators to Observable

// See node_module/rxjs/Rxjs.js
// Import just the rxjs statics and operators we need for THIS app.

// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Comment: Nothing is being output into the console nor is the `extractData` or `handleError` methods ever running

Comment: I accidentally deleted the catch operator, put it back in and now it's back to not doing anything

Comment: Have you subscribed it. Observables are lazy, they don't do anything untill you subscribe

Comment: @Siraj I'm not familiar with subscribing what you can see is all that i've done, I was just following the tutorial. I'll will do some research on it when I can get back to it this afternoon

Comment: @Siraj Thanks for pointing out the obvious. I was having this same problem developing a new service. I had forgotten to subscribe! It looked identical to my other services. I was going nuts looking for the bug.

Comment: Siraj, Thank you for the find.  I was having the same issue and going crazy.